# Options to reduce size of trained model protobuf file from TF object detection API

Tags: protocol-buffers, object-detection-api

I am looking for options to reduce size of trained model file. I have got a trained model exported as graph into .pb file. Model is coming out of TF Object Detection API and by default with this API, trained model gets exported into .pb file.
Is it possible to save this file into any other format where size of the model will be smaller than what I have now?
Current protobuf file size is around 18MB

I do not have idea how this can be done